# how do I find the mysql server name in cpanel? I need it for sequel pro

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to setup my databases in [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) (a mysql app). Localhost won't do. Any idea how I can get server name?

Comment: If you're using a hosting provider, check your admin panel. I know that GoDaddy's SecureServer.net hosting requires very specific server names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the IP address or host name of your server.

Answer (score 1):

Your MySQL server name is often te same as your website domain (e.g. `example.com`).

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connection-access.html:

> Your identity is based on two pieces of information:
>
> - The client host from which you connect
>
>   Your MySQL user name

So even if you've know your host, you have to allow remote connections with a specified user. Please see [this guide](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/php-mysql/mysql_access_host.htm) for that. Your [IP address](http://www.whatismyip.com/) could be entered as host.

Answer (score 0):

Try  your websites domain, also check to see if the mysql server allows remote connections.