# How to find server name in share cpanel sql database?

Tags: mysql, cpanel

First of all I should mention maybe this question already posted but I couldn't find a solution. Let me explain it to you.

I want to compare two databases on my server using DB compare. I need server name. 
I added host name as server name. [reference here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127593/how-do-i-find-the-mysql-server-name-in-cpanel-i-need-it-for-sequel-pro) but it doesn't work.

I added my IP address in Remote MySQL too but it's still same. I mean I got error

**It's failed  to connect to server**

**

> Please guide me how to find Server Name is Cpanel Share server ?

**

Thank you

Comment: which version of DB compare are you using? The versons im seeing currently are all SQL server ones, not MySQL

Comment: version 3 in http://www.dbcomparer.com/

Comment: That product is not compatible with mysql

Comment: oh really? what should I use ?

Comment: you could consider using the built in function of mysql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/mysqldbcompare.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the product description

"DBComparer is a professional database comparison tool for analyzing the differences in **Microsoft SQL Server** 2008 (and 2005) database structures."

it is not compatible with mysql

Comment: I believe server name is something else not domain name cause I already did it several times. no It should be something else

Comment: SO, How to compare Mysql in Cpanel ?

Answer (score 0):

Best method to get Hostname of domain is to use rDNS lookup.

it's very simple, open below website and put your domain

Check here: http://www.intodns.com/

and then find keyword **Your reverse (PTR) record** and your will see your hostname of reverse IP.

Example for facebook.com:  `18.159.220.66.in-addr.arpa ->  msgin-shv-08-frc3.facebook.com`

or you can get by terminal command by `#host xx.xx.xx.xx` xx will be your server IP

It will show like this:

```
root@server [~]# host 66.220.158.68  
68.158.220.66.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer edge-star-mini-shv-07-frc3.facebook.com.
```